# Getting following exception with quartz end point and file to string transformer

Tags: mule

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot apply transformer FileToString{this=2e93ba04,
name='File_to_String', ignoreBadInput=false, 
returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}, 
sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.io.File, mimeType='*/*'}, 
SimpleDataType{type=java.io.FileInputStream, mimeType='*/*'}]}
on source payload: class org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$7.
```

following is the snippet of our code.

```
<quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000"
            doc:name="Quartz" cronExpression="0 0/3 * * * ? *" repeatInterval="0"
            jobName="ApptioStart" >
            <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
                <quartz:job-endpoint ref="fileConnector"/>
            </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>

        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="#[message.outboundProperties]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <!-- Read file from predefined folder path <file:inbound-endpoint path="${csv.folder.path}" 
            responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" /> -->
        <file:file-to-string-transformer
            doc:name="File to String" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there:

```
<quartz:job-endpoint ref="fileConnector"/>
```

`ref` should be referencing a global endpoint and not a connector. This is why the payload of the message is an `org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector`, which leads to the exception.

So create a global file endpoint by placing this outside of a flow:

```
<file:endpoint name="csvFileEndpoint"
      path="${csv.folder.path}" 
      responseTimeout="10000"
      doc:name="CSV Files" />
```

Then use it in your Quartz endpoint:

```
<quartz:job-endpoint ref="csvFileEndpoint"/>
```

References:

- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Quartz+Transport+Reference#QuartzTransportReference-EndpointPollingJob
- https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.6.2/transports/quartz/src/test/resources/quartz-polling-functional-test.xml#L34

Comment: Hi David, We have created a  global endpoint and named it as 'fileConnector'

Comment: WAT. That's a very confusing name for an endpoint! Can you add its config to your question please?